# Jsonp callback function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am doing an example on webservices and i want to return json using `jsonp` callback function.
I have implemented spring on my server side

here is my code

```
$("#button5").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("....webServices/rest/hello/jsonp?callback=?",                   
       function(result){
         //response data are now in the result variable
         alert("jsonp");//NOT printing
    });
});
```

This is my server-side code

```
@GET
@Path("/jsonp")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person sayJsonpHello()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setID(1);
    person.setName("person1");
    System.out.println("jsonp hello");
    return person;
}
```

when i execute the url in the rest client on **chrome** it says `"unexpected token c"`

I am able to return json but not jsonp...that is the callback function is not working.
I have gone through other links in stackoverflow but it dint help.

Is there any configuration i need to set up on the server side.

This is the other option i have tried

```
  $("#button5").click(function () {
        alert("button5");
        $.getJSON("....../webServices/rest/hello/jsonp?callback=callbackFunction",     function (result) {
            alert("jsonp"); //NOT printing
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    });

    function callbackFunction()
    {
        alert("call back function");
    }

The corresponding code on server-side

@GET
@Path("/jsonp")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String  sayJsonpHello()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setID(1);
    person.setName("shalini");
    System.out.println("jsonp hello");
    return "callbackFunction("+person+")";
}
```

updating - answer for my question ( posting after i solved the issue )
My mistake was - @Produces("application/x-javascript") should be used instead of @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON). The reurn type should be JSONWithPadding instead of string

Server side

```
    @GET
    @Path("/jsonp")
    @Produces("application/x-javascript")
    public JSONWithPadding sayJsonpHello()
   {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setID(1);
    person.setName("google");
    System.out.println("jsonp hello");
    return new JSONWithPadding(person,"callbackFunction");
    }
```

UI

```
  $("#button5").click(function() {
        var url = '...../webServices/rest/hello/jsonp?callback=callbackFunction';
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : url,
            data : {},
            async : true,
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error' + errorThrown);
            },
        });
    });
```

The callback function should be visible. That is take care of the scope.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function callbackFunction() 
 {
    alert("call back function");
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Try it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Ltoepz6h/** and see what you get in the console (F12)

Comment: It says [Object, "parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected token :], when i click on the button the second time. On first click there is no error.

Comment: That means you're not getting valid JSONP back.

Comment: I have added the server-side code ..please check.

Comment: I have no idea what output that server side code would give. Look in the Net tab of the developer tools in your browser. Show us the data from the response to the Ajax request.

Comment: Looks like it would produce just regular JSON, and that's not the same as JSONP.

Comment: Its the same output [Object, "parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected token :].  I have replied to adeneo.( second comment )

Comment: @user2768984 — That looks like an error message on the JS console, not the output in the HTTP response.

Comment: I have added the other option i have tried..please check

Comment: It looks like an error in your server code, verify that the server response is a valid JSON object that is passed into callbackFunction().

Comment: @user2768984 — Can you add the *output* from the server side function.

Comment: Sorry Quetin ...the answer to ur first question is wrong. This is the response {"name":"shalini","id":1}.

Comment: Further investigation proved that i was not returning the correct result from the server side. I had to send the return type as "application/javascript" .... now i am sending the correct code from the server side.  But still on the client side the callBack is not working.

Comment: Solved the issue. I have updated  the answer (see above).